# Error whilst trying to delete string from a 'txt' file - Contacts list program

Tags: python

I'm creating a Contact list/book program which can create new contacts for you. Save them in a *'txt'* file. List all contacts, and delete existing contacts. Well sort of. In my delete function there is an error which happens and I can't quite tell why?. There isn't a error prompted on the shell when running. It's meant to ask the user which contact they want to delete, find what the user said in the *'txt'* file. Then delete it. It can find it easily, however it just doesn't delete the string at all.

I have tried other methods including if/else statements, other online code **(copied)** - nothing works.

```
import os, time, random, sys, pyautogui


#function for creating a new contact.
def new_contact():


    name = str(input("Clients name?\n:"))

    name = name + " -"

    info = str(input("Info about the client?\n:"))

    #starts formatting clients name and info for injection into file.

    total = "\n\n"
    total = total + name
    total = total + " "
    total = total + info
    total = total + "\n"
    #Injects info into file.


    with open("DATA.txt", "a") as file:

        file.write(str(total))
        file.close

    main()

#function for listing ALL contacts made.
def list():


    file = open("DATA.txt", "r")
    read = file.read()
    file.close


    #detects whether there are any contacts at all. If there are none the only str in the file is "Clients:"
    if read == "Clients:":
        op = str(input("You havn't made any contacts yet..\nDo you wish to make one?\n:"))


        if op == "y":
            new_contact()


        else:
            main()

    else:
        print (read)
        os.system('pause')
        main()


#Function for deleting contact
def delete_contact():


    file = open("DATA.txt", "r")
    read = file.read()
    file.close


    #detects whether there are any contacts at all. If there are none the only str in the file is "Clients:"
    if read == "Clients:":
        op = str(input("You havn't made any contacts yet..\nDo you wish to make one?\n:"))


        if op == "y":
            new_contact()


        else:
            main()


    else:
        #tries to delete whatever was inputted by the user.
        file = open("DATA.txt", "r")
        read = file.read()
        file.close


        print (read, "\n")


        op = input("copy the Clinets name and information you wish to delete\n:")

        with open("DATA.txt") as f:
            reptext=f.read().replace((op), '')


        with open("FileName", "w") as f:
            f.write(reptext)
            main()


#Main Menu Basically.
def main():


    list_contacts = str(input("List contacts? - L\n\n\nDo you want to make a new contact - N\n\n\nDo you want to delete a contact? - D\n:"))


    if list_contacts in ("L", "l"):
        list()


    elif list_contacts in ("N", "n"):
        new_contact()


    elif list_contacts in ("D", "d"):
        delete_contact()


    else:
        main()



main()
```

It is expected to delete everything the user inputs from the txt file. No errors show up on shell/console, it's as if the program thinks it's done it, but it hasn't. The content in the txt file contains:

Clients:

Erich - Developer

Bob - Test subject

Answer (score 0):

In your delete function, instead of opening DATA.txt, you open "FileName"

Answer (score 0):

When using “with”, a file handle doesn't need to be closed. Also, file.close() is a function, you didnt call the function, just its address.
In addition, in the delete function, you opened “fileName” instead of “DATA.txt”

Comment: Even when I change the mode to "a" when opening the file nothing happens. How can I get the program to actually delete what the user inputs from the 'txt' file?

Comment: It might me because you are replacing a tuple. Try: reptext=f.read().replace(op, '')

Comment: where should change this, sorry?

Comment: In the delete function, after the input

Comment: I figured out how to fix the code! All i needed to do was make everything that was in the txt file a string variable. Than replace the users input from that. Then write the replaced variable to the text file. Thank you all for helping.